# jquery equivalent for css3 transition ease-in

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-transitions

I want to make a jquery version of this css3 effect so that it also works in ff and ie:

```
  a:hover {color: #354250; -webkit-transition:background 500ms ease-in;}
    a.more:hover, a.more:focus, a.more:active {background-position: 0 -18px;}
    a.more:link, a.more:visited {
  background: url(images/moreButton.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height:18px;
  margin-top:10px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width:77px;
}
```

My tries didn't work, here is what I'
ve got so far.

```
    $("a.more").hover(function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#354250', backgroundPosition: '0px -18px' }, slow, function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#ad5332', backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'}, 0);
   });
}, function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#ad5332', backgroundPosition: '0px 0px' }, 0);
});
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: First, look it up: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jquery+animate+background+position&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8. Also, you don't need to nest animations like that, you can just chain them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/), it has great built in features from jQuery Ui.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easing plug-in for Jquery:

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/#example

In order to animate background properties, you need [CSS hooks](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/csshooks-in-jquery-1-4-3/)--check [this](http://pinoytech.org/question/4888024/can-anyone-explain-how-why-to-use-jquerys-css-hooks.) out to read more about them.

Comment: Thank you very much for these interesting links. I will definitely look into them!